# Tk_Init error: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, tcl

On my Ubuntu 20.04 I try to open "qdec" of "freesurfer" and get the following error:

```
Tk_Init error: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /home/username/tcl8.4.6/tk8.4 /home/username/freesurfer/freesurfer/lib/tk8.4 /home/username/freesurfer/lib/tk8.4 /home/username/freesurfer/freesurfer/library /home/username/freesurfer/library /home/username/freesurfer/tk8.4.6/library /home/username/tk8.4.6/library

This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

the rest of freesurfer works (e.g. "freeview") and I am not able to find out how to fix this problem. I think I should somehow install tk8.4.6 in one of the directories it is searching for it or link the directory to an installed version, but I am not sure how to do it. Could someone help me?

edit: freesurfer is a neuroimaging toolbox and qdec is a specific programme of this toolbox. I attached the wiki of the toolbox and the page where I found out about the qdec gui.

freesurfer wiki: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki

qdec introduction: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/FsTutorial/QdecGroupAnalysis_freeview

I installed freesurfer version freesurfer-linux-centos6_x86_64-7.2.0-20210720-aa8f76b

Comment: What are qdec and freesurfer? What was wrong with `tk` and `tcl` packages from official repository? Please make your question more reproducible.

Comment: According to this [FreeSurfer Setup and Configuration](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/SetupConfiguration_Linux) the installation should have come with its own tcl/tk distributions, located in `$FREESURFER_HOME/lib/tcltktixblt`. Do you see anything there?

Comment: @steeldriver: After installing freesurfer, I have several folders in the lib, but no tcltktixblt.. I found: $FREESURFER_HOME/lib/{ tcl, tktools, bem, images, qt, resource, vtk}

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting my folders I realized, that freesurfer was looking in the lib path but not in lib/tktools so I copied everything from the lib/tktools folder into the lib folder, as I did not know how to change the folders it was searching. Now I can run the qdec gui.